# What is the correct way to compress a FileStorage object/image using PIL or another method?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am wanting to compress an image I am receiving from a user before I send it off to an S3 bucket to be stored. Unfortunately for me, I haven't had to deal with images a lot. The image comes over as a FileStorage object and this is where my issue starts. I'm trying to use the PIL library to compress the image using the optimize option when you save your file using PIL. The only issue is I don't have a proper path to save this file. I tried to fake it out to no avail. Is there a proper way to generate a temporary directory/path to save the image just so I can compress it before I send it to the S3 bucket?

Here is the current simple code

```
    file = request.files['filepond']
    # file = Image.open(file)
    # file = file.save('TestDirectory', file.format, optimize=True, quality=30)
    print(file.filename)
    print(file.content_type)
```

Thanks all!

Comment: Is the issue that you can't write to a directory on the machine where you are performing the operation (that seems like an odd restriction). You might consider using [named pipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) instead? Although if it's a file permission issue you are facing, that may not help. Also, important to note that this is a linux/unix thing so if this is running in windows `os.mkfifo` isn't going to work.

Comment: There shouldn't be any restrictions on writing directories. Although I will give named pipes a look.